# What is the difference between actioncontext and actionInvocation struts2?

Tags: struts2, actioncontext

I have a little confusion regarding ActionContext and ActionInvocation. I know that Action Context is the context where Action is being executed. Does ActionInvocation lies within ActionContext like Session, Value Stack etc ?
Secondly, Does ActionContext created on every user request as it is unique per thread ? If so, does this is too costly to create every time a new Action Context on every user request ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have idea about `ActionContext` as a context in which an Action is being executed and for execution of Action's we need Invocation also.
It's a part of the ActionContext and you have all way to get `ActionInvocation` from the context by

```
public ActionInvocation getActionInvocation()
```

Contexts use ThreadLocals, which means that values stored in the ActionContext are unique per thread.
Well for me this is not any overhead as in other case you  have to make sure that everything being accessed in the multi-threaded application is Thread safe.a new `ActionContext` will be created for each request.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between Struts 2 ActionContex and Action Invocation

The ActionContext is a container of objects in which action is executed. The values stored in the ActionContext are unique per thread (i.e. ThreadLocal). So we don't need to make our action thread safe.

We can get the reference of ActionContext by calling the getContext() method of ActionContext class. It is a static factory method. For example: 
ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();

Action Invocatioin :--

The ActionInvocation represents the execution state of an action. It holds the action and interceptors objects.

The struts framework provides ActionInvocation interface to deal with ActionInvocation. It provides many methods, some of them can be used to get the instance of ValueStack, ActionProxy, ActionContext, Result etc.
Methods of ActionInvocation Interface
The commonly used methods of ActionInvocation interface are as follows:

1)public ActionContext getInvocationContext() returns the ActionContext object associated with the ActionInvocation.

2)public ActionProxy getProxy() returns the ActionProxy instance holding this ActionInvocation.

3)public ValueStack getStack() returns the instance of ValueStack.

4)public Action getAction() returns the instance of Action associated with this ActionInvocation.

5)public void invoke() invokes the next resource in processing this ActionInvocation.

6)public Result getResult() returns the instance of Result.